# Is it possible to use Resteasy to post byte[] to invoke rest api?

Tags: java, resteasy, wildfly-10

I'm using Java EE7, wildfly 11, resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.24(bundled in wildfly11)

I have invoked rest api successfully by post json or xml format.

```
private byte[] request(String address, String api, byte[] request, String token) {

        WebTarget resource = ResteasyClient.getClient().target(address);
        Response response = null;
        byte[] entity = null;
        try {
            WebTarget myResource = resource.path(api);
            response = myResource.request(StaticStringUtil.RESPONSE_TYPE)
                    .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token)
                    .async()
                    .post(Entity.json(request)).get();
                    //.post(Entity.entity(request, "application/octet-stream")).get(); // comment 1
                    //.post(Entity.entity(request, "*/*").get(); // comment 2

            entity = response.readEntity(request.getClass());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return entity;
    }
```

But the request you see is byte[], if I convert to json, and web server get the json then convert to byte[] then send to rest api. So is there a way to send byte[] to rest api directly?

I use the `comment 1` and get

> 10:37:22,223 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-4) RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003200: Could not find message body reader for type: class cn.shijinet.kunlun.cia.rest.metadata.GrantTokenRequest of content type: application/octet-stream
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.throwReaderNotFound(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:52)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.getReader(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:75)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:52)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalVerificationInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(DigitalVerificationInterceptor.java:34)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:55)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:59)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:55)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:151)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:91)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:114)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>       at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:226)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:124)
>       at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.picketlink.http.internal.SecurityFilter.processRequest(SecurityFilter.java:356)
>       at org.picketlink.http.internal.SecurityFilter.performOutboundProcessing(SecurityFilter.java:241)
>       at org.picketlink.http.internal.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:196)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>       at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
>       at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

This error shows in client side.

I use the `comment 2` and get

> 5:46:13,110 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-6) RESTEASY002005: Failed executing POST /gje/grantToken: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshalException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>    - with linked exception:
>   [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.]
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.readFrom(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:136)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:66)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:56)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalVerificationInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(DigitalVerificationInterceptor.java:36)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:59)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:151)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:92)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:115)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:406)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:213)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:228)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>       at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:226)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:124)
>       at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.picketlink.http.internal.SecurityFilter.processRequest(SecurityFilter.java:356)
>       at org.picketlink.http.internal.SecurityFilter.performOutboundProcessing(SecurityFilter.java:241)
>       at org.picketlink.http.internal.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:196)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>       at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
>       at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

This error shows in server side. It means resteasyclient send byte[] to server. But issue happens when invoking the service. I set a breakpoint on AbstractJAXBProvider.java, and find the `is.getByteStream().read()`, the value is `123`, which is `{` in ASCII. I send the byte[] which is a json String. But which the server use jaxb to unmarshalling it? How can I change the Provider?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my rest client and modify method to pass your authorization in header and request payload, see DELETE method definition to see how to pass Authorization.
https://github.com/gajeralalji/JAVA-REST-Client/wiki

Comment: Thanks buddy. But I'm not saying passing authorization token as byte[], I mean passing request body as byte[].